# why we need routing middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

why we need routing middleware

when app.UseMvc as shown in below code is good enough for routing.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

Comment: This covers only the simplest cases. You may have areas at somepoint, api endpoints (which start with `api/{controller}/{id?]` and don't have actions), multiple urls pointing to the same action, routes encoded with language/locale etc.

Comment: I was going through the samples of asp.net core from Github - https://github.com/amicalrahul/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/controllers/routing/sample/AreasRouting/Startup.cs             and found that even area routing can be defined using app.usemvc as shown below:#if First
            #region snippet1
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapAreaRoute("blog_route", "Blog",
                    "Manage/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute("default_route", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
            #endregion

Comment: I am still not able to understand the correct rational. app.UseMVC internally creates the routebuilder (i.e. routing middleware). So what could be the specific use case where we cannot simply call app.UseMVC but have to rely on routingmiddleware. We can define even multiple routes via app.UseMVC

Comment: Another doubt on the same : We also have attribute based routing so for any complex routes, we can define that in the controllers. So again, what is the use routing middleware

Comment: Attributes are still handled by routing middleware, so you will always need it. Actually the `UseMvc` extension method just configures the Routing middleware https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L91-L100

Comment: Thanks. That clears my doubt.